# Ubuntu 18.10 GUI does not load when NVidia drivers are installed

Tags: boot, nvidia, 18.10, nouveau

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 with Linux 4.18.0 Kernel on Ryzen 1700 with NVidia GTX 1050 graphics card.

The system works normally when Nouveau drivers are used. However when I try to use the NVidia open-source drivers, the system shows the splash screen during boot, then goes into terminal, which shows something like `Starting disk manager` or `Starting network manager`, and the system completely freezes up. Even the Caps Lock light doesn't respond anymore, after which I have to restart the system again.

The problem goes away when I use `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf'. But the boot and login takes more time.

The problem also goes away when I continuously mash `CTRL+ALT+F4/F3` during boot and log in from terminal and then switch to GUI.

I have used NVidia driver version 390, 410 and 415.

Is there any way to alleviate the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem and though it is too early to say if I fixed it, things seem better with a different display manager rather than the gnome (gdm3) that is the default with 18.10.  You can change to lightdm like this

> sudo apt-get install lightdm
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

I don't know if the second command is really necessary.

The only problem I've seen so far is the dropbox status icon no longer shows up in the top bar.

I am running the 410.73 Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Yeah, that works. GDM3 and Wayland is like kryptonite for NVidia.

Comment: I was using Xorg and gdm3 and still had problems.  Another issue I found with my current setup is that if the screen saver goes on during the hours when "night light" is enabled, the night light setting isn't applied after the screen comes back on. I can deal with that since now my computer boots.